# Attachment with -A option in mailx not working in Ubuntu 20.04,

Tags: email, mail

Attachment with -A option in mailx not working in Ubuntu 20.04
Body also coming as attachment when we use -A option

1)Example Code :-

echo -e  "Hi Team\n\nPlease find attached report.\n\nRegards\nMuthu" |mailx -a "From:<from_email>" -s "subject" mail_to --attach="test.txt"

echo -e  "Hi Team\n\nPlease find attached report.\n\nRegards\nMuthu" |mailx -a "From:<from_email>" -s "subject" mail_to -A "test.txt"

2. No error code since didn't get any error
3. "echo -e  "Hi Team\n\nPlease find attached VM list.\n\nRegards\nMuthu" also coming as separate attachment in email with test.txt instead of email's body.
4. Need to send email with attachment using mailx

Comment: Apologies, but there simply isn't enough here to work with. If you would like an answer you can actually use, please [edit] your question to include: (0) an example of your code (1) any error message you're seeing (2) an example of the output (3) what you actually want. Without this, the bulk of the effort is put on the person answering the question rather than the person seeking an answer, which just isn't fair when approaching a community-led project such as AskUbuntu ... 

Comment: @matigo My apologies !! It's done !